# How add two text objects

Tags: r, text, sum

How add sum information from two texts? Example:

```
obj1 <- c("A","E","I","O","U")
```

Now, how can I have an object with “BA”, “BE”,… “BU”? I tried:

```
obj2=c("B"+ obj1)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and give a complete code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in R,

```
obj1 = c("A","E","I","O","U")
obj2 = paste("B", obj1,sep='')`
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I forgot to say that it was in R language.